# Compiling Error when passing an array/pointers into a procedure in a library

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, arduino, eeprom

I am having an issue with passing an array into function which is contained in a library. I am using the Arduino IDE 16.7.
If I pass a non-array/non-pointer variable than the code compiles fine. 
I think I have made a basic flaw with my addresses of pointers. But I am unable to see what it is

Here are the errors I am getting:

- invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'uint8_t {aka unsigned char}' [-fpermissive]
- initializing argument 2 of 'void EEPROMClass::write(int, uint8_t)' [-fpermissive]

Both of these errors are related to the EEPROM Arduino library I am using.

The compiler doesn't seem to agree with my passing of an array/pointer to the EEPROm library like this... Why?

H file:

```
#ifndef EEPROMAnyType_h
#define EEPROMAnyType_h

#include <Arduino.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>

template <class E> 
class EEPROMAnyType
{
    public:
        int EEPROMReadAny(unsigned int addr, E x); //Reads any type of variable EEPROM
        int EEPROMWriteAny(unsigned int addr, E x);//Writes any type of variable to EEPROM
//    EEPROMAnyType(unsigned int addr, E x);
};
//#include "EEPROMAnyType.cpp"
#endif
```

CPP file:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>
#include "EEPROMAnyType.h"



template <class E>
int EEPROMAnyType<E>::EEPROMReadAny(unsigned int addr, E x) 
{
  union{
    byte b[sizeof(x)];
    E y;//generaltype y //have a variable that has no type here(using a tempplate???)
  };

  int i;
  x = x; //assign x to y( a variable of no type) which should be n the union
  y = x;
  for(i = 0; i < sizeof(y); i++){ // Why can I not declare i as an integer in the for loop?
    b[i] = EEPROM.read(addr+i);
  }
  return i;
}

template <class E>
int EEPROMAnyType<E>::EEPROMWriteAny(unsigned int addr, E x)
{
  union{
    byte b[sizeof(x)];
    E y;//generaltype y //have a variable that has no type here(using a tempplate???)
  };
  int i = 0;
  y = x;
  for(i = 0; i < sizeof(y); i++){
    EEPROM.write(addr+i, y);
  }
  return i;
}
```

INO file(implements the library):

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>
#include <EEPROMAnyType.h>
#include <EEPROMAnyType.cpp>
int addressCharArray;
const int writes = 80;
const int memBase = 350;
unsigned int eeaddrPASS;
unsigned int eeaddrSSID;
char eePASS[writes];
char eeSSID[writes];

EEPROMAnyType<char*> eepblueString;//instantiates EEPROMANyType class

boolean check = false;
void setup(){
  if (check = true){
    EEPROMwifiUpdate(eeaddrPASS, eeaddrSSID, eePASS, eeSSID);
  }
}
void loop(){
  EEPROMwifiRead(eeaddrPASS, eeaddrSSID, eePASS, eeSSID);
}

void EEPROMwifiUpdate(unsigned int writeaddrPASS, unsigned int writeaddrSSID, char writePASS[writes], char writeSSID[writes]){
  eepblueString.EEPROMWriteAny(writeaddrPASS, writePASS);
  eepblueString.EEPROMWriteAny(writeaddrSSID, writeSSID);
}

void EEPROMwifiRead(unsigned int readaddrPASS, unsigned int readaddrSSID, char readPASS[writes], char readSSID[writes]){
  eepblueString.EEPROMReadAny(readaddrPASS, readPASS);
  eepblueString.EEPROMReadAny(readaddrSSID, readSSID);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this call

```
for(i = 0; i < sizeof(y); i++){
  EEPROM.write(addr+i, y);
}
```

`y` is (if I'm not wrong) of type `char[]` (more or less `char *`) and the second argment of `EEPROM.write()` should be (according to the error message) a `uint8_t` (similar to a `char`)

I suppose you should write something like

```
for(i = 0; i < sizeof(y); ++i){
  EEPROM.write(addr+i, y[i]);
}
```

or (using the union)

```
for(i = 0; i < sizeof(b); ++i){
  EEPROM.write(addr+i, b[i]);
}
```

like in `EEPROMReadAny()`.

Unrelated suggestion: taking in count that you confront it with an unsigned value (`sizeof(y)`), it's better if you define `i` (in `EEPROMReadAny()` and in `EEPROMWriteAny()`) `unsigned` or `std::size_t`.

p.s.: sorry for my bad English.

**--- EDIT ---**

Second question: error "invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive] eepBLEtoothchar.EEPROMReadAny(readaddrSSID, readSSID);"

I don't understand this error, but... I see a couple of other problems.

**I problem**

You define `eepblueString`

```
 EEPROMAnyType<char*> eepblueString;
```

as a `EEPROMAnyType<char*>`. So, in `EEPROMAnyType<E>`, the type `E` is a `char *`. And `sizeof(E)` is 4 (or 8, if you are in a 64 bit platform).

When you pass `readPASS` and `readSSID`, they are `char[80]` so, I suppose, your intention is read 80 chars. But your object try to read only 4 (or 8) chars.

**II problem**

The second argument to `EEPROMReadAny()` is passed by **value**; so you can read 4 (or 8) chars but they are loose when you exit from the method. To save the readed chars, you should pass the second argument by reference.

You really need the `EEPROMAnyType`?

I mean: if `EEPROMReadAny()` can be a simple function, you can deduce the `E` type from the second argument, avoiding the first problem.

I propose the following solution (should solve the II problem to, passing the second argument by reference)

```
template <class E>
int EEReadAny (unsigned int add, E & x)
 {
   char * b = (char *)&x;

   for ( unsigned ui = 0U ; ui < sizeof(E) ; ++ui )
      b[ui] = EEPROM.read(addr+i);

   return sizeof(E);
 }
```

Comment: great that fixes that issue, but I am getting a new error: invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]

Comment: Also I am getting this interesting error with just passing a String type through:                                                                                        - 'EEPROMAnyType<E>::EEPROMReadAny(unsigned int, E) [with E = String]::<anonymous union>::~<constructor>()' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:

   union{

Comment: What does this mean? Can I even pass a String type? What is wrong with the constructor destrcutor? I know I have not initialized one but that should be initialized by itself anyway shouldn't it?

Comment: About the "invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'char'", I suppose there is another point with a similar problem of conversion; you shoul show us the full message to understand where the problem is and the relative code. About the problem, a `std::string` is illegal in a C++ union pre C++11 (and dangerous in C++11/C++14); give a look, for this, at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37002058/compiling-error-when-passing-an-array-pointers-into-a-procedure-in-a-library/37002253?noredirect=1#comment61636284_37002253

Comment: Here is where theconversion error is happening: invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]

   eepBLEtoothchar.EEPROMReadAny(readaddrSSID, readSSID);

Comment: Yes I have found some sources on this. Although I am not sure if I understand it.I don' understand what a special member function is.  haha you sent a link to the same page we are on here :P. Here is the good resource I found: http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=556

Comment: Isn't completely clear to me but... I try to add an edit to the response